# how to resolve for UnicodeDecode Error from sys.stdin in python for?

Tags: python

The moment we have this code it throws up error. I don't want to save the details in a file and process it as suggested in some other posts.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    temp = ''
```

Traceback:

```
> for line in sys.stdin:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line
> 322, in decode
>     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position
> 2669: invalid start byte
```

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Is it just a command line program, or perhaps run in a a window or IDE? I don't understand what you mean about details in a file... is there something else we should know?

Comment: What is the value in `sys.stdin.encoding` and what is returned from `locale.getpreferredencoding()`? You could change your program to read undecoded byte strings `for line in sys.stdin.buffer: print(line)` and then try your own decode `line.decode('utf-8')` to see which one has the bad data.

Comment: @tdelaney >> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'UTF-8'

Comment: I would like to read raw mail using the above standard input code

Comment: If you are working in Windows, it is likely that your input file is encoded as cp1252, in which `0xa0` is a non-breaking space.

Comment: i work with linux, python 3.6

Comment: "Read raw mail..." - How is the program run? Is the stdin of the progam a terminal that you are typing into? Or is there some sort of redirection like piping a file?

Comment: have read raw mail, but to increase speed  need to read from standard input using python script, without using any parsers